# replacing values in a data frame in R depending on column sums

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
GooseIPA HeadHunter BlindPig MosaicPromise HopHunter
9 10 8 6 10
0 6 8 4 1
0 2 3 1 0
```

If the `colSums <=10` I want to replace all values in that column with NA.

The output would look like this:

```
 GooseIPA HeadHunter BlindPig MosaicPromise HopHunter
NA 10 8 6 10
NA 6 8 4 1
NA 2 3 1 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method with `sapply`.

```
is.na(df) <- sapply(df, function(x) (sum(x) < 10))
```

The idea is that `sapply` loops through the variables and checks whether the sum of each is less than 10, if yes, TRUE is assigned to `is.na`.

```
df
  GooseIPA HeadHunter BlindPig MosaicPromise HopHunter
1       NA         10        8             6        10
2       NA          6        8             4         1
3       NA          2        3             1         0
```

The same method, but probably faster with `colSums` is

```
is.na(df) <- (colSums(df) < 10)
```

**data**

```
df <- 
dput(df)
structure(list(GooseIPA = c(9L, 0L, 0L), HeadHunter = c(10L, 
6L, 2L), BlindPig = c(8L, 8L, 3L), MosaicPromise = c(6L, 4L, 
1L), HopHunter = c(10L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("GooseIPA", "HeadHunter", 
"BlindPig", "MosaicPromise", "HopHunter"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data frame is called `df`, then you can use:

```
      df[,colSums(df)<=10]<-NA
```